# Unable to run apt-get within docker build

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt-get

I have an `Dockerfile` that's installing `ffmpeg` and for some reason i get error that says no pub key.

```
FROM dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc

WORKDIR /data

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ffmpeg
```

This is the error I get:

> #0 13.99 W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
> public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
> #0 13.99 E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.

I have tried to add this key by running this command with the key I get but nothing is changed and the error remain.

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B`

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing GPG public key for the Google Chrome repository and `apt-get` cant verify the package.

Lets add it:

```
FROM dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc

WORKDIR /data

# Add the missing GPG key
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B

# Install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your GPG key expired. Quick fix:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```